# M power query - rebuild this data combination

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

Getting the error message on the below query in M, I've tried splitting into 2 different queries before the merge step but still getting the 'this does not directly access a data source, please rebuild the data combination' error

```
*let
    Source = #"Query List from SP",
    cols = if {"Type"} = "Indicator" then 4 else 5,
    DataLoad = (path) =>
    let
       Doc =
           Csv.Document(
               Web.Contents(
                    BaseUrl,
                    [Headers =[#"Content-type"="text/csv",
                               #"Authorization"="Basic " & Credential],
                     RelativePath=path
                    ]), [Delimiter=",", Columns=cols, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
                    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Doc, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
                    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Data", type text}, {"Organisation unit", type text}, {"Period", type text}, {"Value", type number}}
)
      in
         #"Changed Type",
     out = Table.AddColumn(
           Source,
           "res",
           each DataLoad([Path])
           ),
     #"Removed Errors" = Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(out, {"res"}),
    #"Expanded res" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Errors", "res", {"Data", "Category option combo", "Organisation unit", "Period", "Value"}, {"Data", "Category option combo", "Organisation unit", "Period.1", "Value"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded res",{"GUIDs", "Period", "BaseUrl", "Credential", "Path"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"Value", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Period.1", "Period"}}),
    #"Replace Cat" = Table.RenameColumns(Table.RemoveColumns(Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "colnew", each if [Data] = "VbgQkVibB4P" then "qCWoTDpiKeH" 
else if [Data] = "YfCLQ1zig8z" then "qCWoTDpiKeH" 
else if [Data] = "M6kVOHWcnK3" then "qCWoTDpiKeH" 
else if [Data] = "Wov7FpjPr4E" then "qCWoTDpiKeH" 
else if [Data] = "MTuFYrvAacn" then "qCWoTDpiKeH" 
else if [Data] = "uXuoTc5nxkd" then "qCWoTDpiKeH" 
else if [Data] = "DsLkV0VYy6q" then "qCWoTDpiKeH"
else [Category option combo]),{"Category option combo"}),{{"colnew", "Category option combo"}}),
    #"Inserted Merged Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Replace Cat", "deco key", each Text.Combine({[Data], [Category option combo]}, "."), type text),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Inserted Merged Column", "Index", 1, 1)
in
    #"Added Index"*
```

Comment: This may help: https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2015/03/11/power-query-errors-please-rebuild-this-data-combination/

Answer (score 2):

You are not directly accessing the data source since you are linking to the query `#"Query List from SP"`.

Much has been written on this topic. Chris Webb has a whole [blog series](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2017/06/26/data-privacy-settings-in-power-bipower-query-part-3-the-formula-firewall-error/) related to data privacy settings, but the easiest way to get rid of this problem is to simply ignore privacy levels.

Go to Options and settings under the file menu:

[image: Options and settings]

Under the Privacy section choose to ignore the privacy levels:

[image: Privacy Levels]

Obviously, if you're building something that needs to manage privacy levels carefully, then this is the wrong approach and you'll need to be more careful. But when privacy levels aren't a concern, this is a simple and convenient fix