# PowerBI Regular Expression Using M or Python

Tags: python, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, m

I've never used Python inside of PowerBI before, but I have used Python. I'm happy with a Python or M language solution though.

Let's say I have a column that looks like this:

```
EntryTime
12:00:00 - 01:10:00
01:00:30 - 05:10:50
2020-11-03 R
2010-03-31 R
2020-04-01 R
```

I want to replace all values that contain this format, and is case insensitive, with `NULL` values:

```
yyyy-MM-dd( )+[R]
```

How can I implement this in PowerBI using either M or Python? Please be very specific as I have not used Python inside of PowerBI before.

Comment: What is your expected output? `NULL` values for last 3 rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`M` does not have native functions to perform any Regex operations. You can use `Python`.

Step 1: Change the column datatype of `EntryTime` to `Text`.

[image]

Step 2: Go to `Transform` -> `Run Python Script`

Step 3: Paste the below code and click `ok`.

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
import pandas as pd
pat = r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} R'
dataset["New"] = dataset["EntryTime"].str.replace(pat,'')
```

Step 4: You will get a window with `Name` and `Value` like below.

[image]

Step 5: Click the `Table` under `Value` column. You will get results as shown below.

[image]

Comment: I get an error message "formula.firewall: query 'SessionData' references other queries or steps so it may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The easiest solution to that is to ignore privacy level settings https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51823280