# PowerBI - how to get an output from one query to another? (For Sophos Central APIs)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I want to get the output of the first query (SophosBearerToken) to the other one, but it gives me the following error

> Formula.Firewall: Query 'Query2' (step 'PartnerID') references other
> queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please
> rebuild this data combination.

first query : SophosBearerToken (works)

```
    let
    SophosBearerToken = "Bearer " & (Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://id.sophos.com/api/v2/oauth2/token",
        [
            Headers = [#"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],
            Content = Text.ToBinary("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" & #"SophosClientID" & "&client_secret=" & #"SophosClientSecret" & "&scope=token")
        ]
    )) [access_token])
in
    SophosBearerToken
```

second query: Query2(fail)

```
let
    PartnerIDQuery = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.central.sophos.com/whoami/v1", [Headers = [#"Authorization"=#"SophosBearerToken"]])),
    PartnerID = PartnerIDQuery[id]
in
    PartnerID
```

but when I add the output of the first query manually to the second one it works

what could be the mistake I'm doing in here?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51823280

Comment: Alexis Olson provided link works, thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51823280